# Arrays working $elemMatch for $or and $and scenarios

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming exists the following data for simplicity.

```
[
    {
        "special_colors": ["Blue", "Black", "Red"],
    },
    {
        "special_colors": ["Blue", "Green", "Red"],
    },
    {
        "special_colors": ["Black", "Blue", "Red"],
    }
]
```

If I execute:

```
db.fighters.find({"special_colors.2": "Red"}, {"_id": 0}).pretty()
```

It works and returns all documents.

If I execute:

```
db.fighters.find({"special_colors.0": "Blue"}, {"_id": 0}).pretty()
```

It works and returns the *first* and *second* documents.

If I execute:

```
db.fighters.find({"special_colors.1" : "Blue"}, {"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

It works and returns the *third* document.

To retrieve all the documents without matter in what position (index) is located either *Blue* or *Black*, I do the following and works fine:

```
db.fighters.find({"special_colors" : {$elemMatch: {$eq: "Blue"} } }, {"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

**Situation/Scenario**

I want apply a **OR**, it to retrieve all the documents where `special_colors` has either `Blue` **or** `Black` (without matter the position of index), I tried many variations such as:

```
db.fighters.find({"special_colors" : {$elemMatch: {$eq: "Blue", $eq: "Black"} } }, {"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

when is executed returns some documents but only considered the second part (Black) and the first part (Blue) was totally ignored

With

```
db.fighters.find({"special_colors" : {$elemMatch: {$eq: ["Blue", "Black"]} } }, {"_id" : 0, }).pretty()
```

when is executed returns *nothing*

With

```
db.fighters.find({"special_colors" : {$elemMatch: {$or: ["Blue", "Black"] } } }, {"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

when is executed arises the following error message: `$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects`

and with:

```
db.fighters.find({
    "special_colors": {
        $or: [{$elemMatch: {$eq: "Blue"}},
            {$elemMatch: {$eq: "Black"}}
        ]
    }
}, {"_id": 0}).pretty()
```

when is executed arises the following error message: `unknown operator: $or`

So what could be the correct syntax for `OR` and `AND`?

**Therefore**:

- Retrieve all the documents where `special_colors` has either `Blue` **or** `Black` (without matter the position of index)
- Retrieve all the documents where `special_colors` has both `Blue` **and** `Black` (without matter the position of index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Retrieve all the documents where `special_colors` has either `Blue` **or** `Black` (without matter the position of index)*

**[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):**

- Selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array

```
db.fighters.find({
  special_colors: { $in: ["Blue", "Black"] }
},
{"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7k_8WeDCDqR)

**`$or`:** *(equivelant to `$in`)*

- don't need to use `$elemMatch` for array of string

```
db.fighters.find({
  $or: [
    { special_colors: "Blue" },
    { special_colors: "Black" }
  ]
},
{"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uDWG-cQA303)

> *Retrieve all the documents where `special_colors` has both `Blue` **and** `Black` (without matter the position of index)*

**[`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/):**

- Equivalent to an `$and` operation of the specified values

```
db.fighters.find({
  special_colors: {
    $all: ["Blue", "Black"]
  }
},
{"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z3UzgSIQj15)

**`$and`:** *(equivelant to `$all`)*

```
db.fighters.find({
  $and: [
    { special_colors: "Blue" },
    { special_colors: "Black" }
  ]
},
{"_id" : 0}).pretty()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vzZ7oU1WrhO)

Comment: Clearly `$in` and `$all` at a first glance are better because is only mandatory use the field just once

Answer (score 1):

While in theory you can use `$elemMatch` for this it's more suited to be used for nested documents within the array. Because Mongo flattens all arrays for the purpose of queries you can just use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) for your "or" condition and [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) for your "and" condition, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  special_colors: {
    $in: [
      "Blue",
      "Black"
    ]
  }
})
```

Will match any document that has blue or black.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GDW2yfI6coT)

And:

```
db.collection.find({
  special_colors: {
    $all: [
      "Blue",
      "Black"
    ]
  }
})
```

Will match documents that have both colors in their array.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zoN8cI3j4x8)